# Nested loop Triangle with python

Tags: python

I need this nested loop to work and its simple

```
def triangle():
      print("Making a Triangle")
      base = 6
      while base > 0:
            print('0',0,base)
            base = base - 1
 triangle()
```

My current output is:

```
Making a Triangle
0 0 6
0 0 5
0 0 4
0 0 3
0 0 2
0 0 1
```

I need my output to look like this:

```
000000
00000
0000
000
00
0
```

Comment: What do you think `print('0',0,base)` does? Have you tried `print('0' * base)`?

Comment: Though... the above comment by @tobias_k solved your problem for now... please focus on thinking why it solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the multiplication `*` operator to create a string by repeating a character. Also, this would be a very straight forward application for a `for` loop.

```
def triangle(n):
    print('making a triangle')
    for zeroes in range(n):
        print('0' * (n-zeroes))
```

Testing

```
>>> triangle(6)
making a triangle
000000
00000
0000
000
00
0
```

Although if you'd like to stick with a `while` loop, you could do

```
def triangle(n):
    print('Making a triangle')
    while n > 0:
        print('0' * n)
        n -= 1
```